# MySQL: UPDATE query joining 3 tables runs long (15M row tables, indexed)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 15M rows in 3 tables (one table is the original CSV import, the other two are normalized versions of that CSV + some other data).

I need to simply update one field from the original CSV table. The update query joining these tables has now run for 30 hours on my quad-core-8GB-ssd box.

- Is this normal? Is there a better way to perform this simple update?

---

```
Tables: ti (the CSV dump, denormalized, ~13M rows)
        i (the primary, normalized table, ~17M rows)
        icm (a map of ti.raw_id to i.item_id, ~17M rows)

mysql> explain select * from item AS i, item_catalog_map AS icm, temp_input AS ti WHERE i.id=icm.item_id AND icm.catalog_unique_item_id=ti.productID;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref        | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ALL    | PRIMARY              | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL       | 13652592 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | icm   | ref    | IDX_ACD6184F126F525E | IDX_ACD6184F126F525E | 5       | frugg.i.id |        1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ti    | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY              | 767     | func       |        1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> UPDATE item AS i, item_catalog_map AS icm, temp_input AS ti
    -> SET i.name=ti.productName,
    ->     icm.price=ti.retailPrice,
    ->     icm.conversion_url=productURL
    -> WHERE i.id=icm.item_id AND icm.catalog_unique_item_id=ti.productID;
```

Comment: Does an [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) help things?

Comment: @davidparks Generally, you'll have inefficiencies if your tables aren't indexed. What are the database engines used? Eg: InnoDB or ISAM... Then again, if you're using ISAM, everytime you UPDATE a key or Add a record, you're sure to have the tables re-indexed. Finally, running a SELECT and UPDATE are two different things. Still, don't you have a better way than doing a n inner join between the three like this?

Comment: According to your question, you need to only update one field in `i`.  However, your query is also updating two fields in `icm`.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: The tables are surely indexed, 'possible_keys' shows that we're using 2 primary keys and an indexed column (on the map table icm which has no primary). The engine is set to InnoDB. These tables were newly created a week ago, no delete operations, so not sure about optimize table. the only thing of note I might say is that I've used TEXT fields mostly rather than VARCHAR, but I don't see anything out there warning against that for InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your denormalized data has 13M records, but *both* of your "normalized" tables have 17M records, then you are not getting much compression out of your normalization.

Second, you are trying to update both normalized tables in one SQL statement.  I would think that you should update the mapping table first, then in a second SQL statement update the data table.

Third, doing an inner join could speed things up because your query is doing a three-way cartesian product.  Well, not exactly, because you are just doing the join old school, and the optimizer should pick it up, but none-the-less, use the JOIN syntax.

```
UPDATE item_catalog_map AS icm
       INNER JOiN temp_input AS ti
          ON icm.catalog_unique_item_id = ti.productID
  SET icm.price = ti.retailPrice,
      icm.conversion_url = productURL;


UPDATE item AS i
       INNER JOIN temp_input AS ti
          ON i.id = icm.item_id
  SET i.name = ti.productName;
```

Finally, indexes to make sure you have are:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_CATALOG ON item_catalog_map (catalog_unique_item_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_RAW_PRODUCT_ID ON temp_input (productID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_RAW_ITEM_ID ON temp_input (item_id);
```

Comment: The icm table is a map, it's required because there are multiple datasets (think a ti1, ti2, ti3, all different CSV imports) that will map to the i (item) table (many ti to one i rows). Thus the map is necessary to identify duplicates between  ti1, ti2, etc and the i (item) table.

Comment: I've tried your second comment, just updating the mapping table, so just 1 join on primary keys - VARCHAR(255) keys, I'm well over 24 hours now.

Comment: I'm working on the separate updates as you suggested, fingers crossed. :)

Comment: In regard to your first comment, I think the mapping table is necessary for initially creating the item table, and would be needed for creating new records.  However, all you were doing is updating the product name from the CSV import, so I don't think it is needed in the second query.  For creating records, I'd still populate the mapping table without the item table, then have an SQL statement to populate the item table with a join to the mapping table.